# Create a simple redundant network

Tags: networking, redundancy

I am trying to setup a simple home network with an element of redundancy.

I have two Ubuntu servers, each fitted with dual NICs. I also have dual TL-SG1016DE simple smart switches. Both switches connect to a single ADSL router via different powerline adapter links.

[image: Simple network idea]

The 200Mbps powerline link is very reliable but slow, whilst the 500Mbps is quicker but frequently drops out.

I would like for my client PC to normally access the Internet through the 500Mbps link, but when it is down, route via one of the servers and the 200Mbps powerline adapter.

The two servers need to be able to communicate with each other as I will be replicating a database between them.

My idea is to create two subnets, say `192.168.1.x` and `192.168.2.x`.

I believe I can use 'iptables' on the servers to route between the 2 subnets，but I am not sure what commands to use and how to avoid loops etc.?

Another problem is that the ADSL router has to be on a single subnet (I think), i.e. it has an address `192.168.1.1`. Is this a limitation that I can work around so I can get access via either subnet?

As you can probably tell, I only know a few basics about networking. This project (and question) is part of an attempt to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The 200Mbps powerline link is very reliable but slow, whilst the 500Mbps is quicker but frequently drops out.
>
> I would like for my client PC to normally access the internet through the 500Mbps link, but when it is down, route via one of the servers and the 200Mbps powerline.

What you are asking for is redundancy at the [data-link layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer), not the [network layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_layer) (where TCP/IP lives). In other words, if the 500 Mbps link fails, you want to fallback to the 200 Mbps link. You do not want (nor need) multiple IP subnetworks, as this won't provide any functionality to facilitate selecting the fastest working link from your network to the Internet router, nor a way to deal with the loop your network design includes, which regardless of how you have your subnetworks configured, will cause a broadcast storm that will shut your network down.

What you need is the [Spanning Tree Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol) (STP). This is included in most network switches. STP can detect loops created by multiple paths to a single destination in your network. For example, from Switch 1 to the router, and from Switch 2 to the router. It then automatically disables the appropriate port on one of the switches to prevent the loop. Then, should a path fail (e.g. via the 500 Mbps link) STP can automatically enable the backup link, restoring connectivity.

You may need to administratively assign a "weight" to the switch port connected to the 500 Mbps link to give it higher priority so that STP knows you prefer this link be left active and the 200 Mbps link disabled when both are otherwise fully functioning.

Read the linked information about STP, then refer to your switches' manual for information on how to configure STP.

Comment: Thank you for the really helpful answer, this is much easier than I thought it would be! My switches are the 'Easy Smart' variety so the setting is called 'Loop Prevention', which may or may not be STP under the hood. I have edited the text to make it clear that replication is not part of the question.

Comment: @iwbnwif Yes, it's likely the loop prevent is STP under the good.  Good find!